# Remove decimal point from on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, on-screen-keyboard

According to this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393998%28VS.92%29.aspx), numeric keypad on Windows Phone OS 7.1 is ought to have "." - decimal point.

Is there a way to remove the decimal point from keyboard, leaving only numbers and Backspace sign?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to customize the soft input panel further than the various InputScopes. You could, however attempt to simulate the SIP, but that seems like a lot of extra work just to avoid the ".".

Here is one example that might be of help if you choose to go this route: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempt to modify the built in keyboards (which you can't do) or attempt to create a custom keyboard (which is a lot of work to accurately recreate the native experience) you'll probably find it much simpler to just ignore the characters you don't want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TextChanged event to check for the period and ignore it.